# keep service alive even when app closed

Tags: java, android

I have searched but yet got nothing. My question is: how can I make my service to not close when the application is. I have a chat app so I need even when application is closed, the service keeps listening for messages.

I have tried

```
 android:process=":my_process"
```

But this causes the service to be like "A separate application" from main and so can not recognize my activities to send any thing.

Also obviously I don't want my service to be bound.

```
public class MyService extends Service {
public static final String HOST = "192.168.1.102";
  public static final int PORT = 5222;
  public static final String SERVICE = "reza-hp";
  public static final String USERNAME = "reza";
  public static final String PASSWORD = "pro";
  private ArrayList<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>();
  private Handler mHandler = new Handler();


  //public static Handler mHandler = new Handler();
public static  ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new   
ConnectionConfiguration(HOST, PORT, SERVICE);
public static XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);  
  //  ArrayList<String> messages = XMPPChatDemoActivity.messages; 

  @Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    return null;
}
// @Override
// public void onCreate() {
//  connect();  
//  setConnection(connection);
//this must be called again on reconnect
};

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

BusProvider.getInstance().register(this);

 connect();


return START_STICKY;
}







public void connect() {


//  if (connection != null) {
//   final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Connecting...", 
"Please wait...", false);
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    // Create a connection
     try {
       connection.connect();
       Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity",  "[SettingsDialog] Connected to  
"+connection.getHost());
     } catch (XMPPException ex) {
         Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity",  "[SettingsDialog] Failed to connect to "+ 

connection.getHost());
         Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", ex.toString());

    }


     try {
          if (!connection.isAuthenticated()) {

        connection.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity",  "Logged in as" + connection.getUser());
          }
        // Set the status to available
        Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
        try {
            connection.sendPacket(presence);
        } catch (NotYetConnectedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
        Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
        for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {

          Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity",  "--------------------------------------");
          Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "RosterEntry " + entry);
          Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "User: " + entry.getUser());
          Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Name: " + entry.getName());
          Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Status: " + entry.getStatus());
          Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Type: " + entry.getType());
          Presence entryPresence = roster.getPresence(entry.getUser());

          Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence Status: "+ 
 entryPresence.getStatus());
          Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence Type: " + entryPresence.getType());

          Presence.Type type = entryPresence.getType();

          if (type == Presence.Type.available)
            Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence AVIALABLE");
            Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence : " + entryPresence);
          }
          } catch (XMPPException ex) {
            Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Failed to log in as "+  USERNAME);
            Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", ex.toString());

          }
   //       dialog.dismiss();
  }


  });
BusProvider.getInstance().post(new ButtonEvent());
t.start();
//  dialog.show();


}




 public void setConnection(XMPPConnection connection) {
this.connection = connection;
if (connection != null) {
  // Add a packet listener to get messages sent to us
  PacketFilter filter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.chat);

  connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
 @Override
     public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
      Message message = (Message) packet;
      if (message.getBody() != null) {
        String fromName = StringUtils.parseBareAddress(message.getFrom());
        Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity ", " Text Recieved " + message.getBody() + " from  
 " +  fromName);
        messages.add(fromName + ":");
        messages.add(message.getBody());
        Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity",message.getBody());
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
    //        setListAdapter();
          }
        });
      }
    }
   }, filter);

  }
 }





}
```

Comment: Is this the right way to go about this? Running a service persistently in the background is a massive resource drainer. You need some sort of intermediate storage for messages that is possibly checked routinely by an IntentService from your app, that then updates a local database and/or informs the user that a message awaits. I've never written a chat app before though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Sticky service

is the way to go, This will make the service automatically start after being killed by another process

Try below

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) { 
    // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly stopped, so return sticky.       
   return START_STICKY;
 }
```

For further information, Read documentation: [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

Hope this helps

Comment: i have this added, but still when i close the app, service also closes and i get logged off

Comment: How are you closing the app? Even if you kill a service running sticky manually, it will come back again. Need to show more code.

Comment: well i ended up using onback key press, its even more suitable for a messenger application, i dont want it to bother, ill put an exit button for that later

Comment: any way i post the full code now , that would be my pleasure if you take a look into that